# How to set unique folders for several e-mail accounts?

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using more and more e-mail lately and I would like to put some order into that. The thing is that I have two different accounts  (Yahoo and Google).

I created a folder in Thunderbird for my Gmail account named "Work".
I have received a mail on my yahoo account that is about work.
When I put this e-mail into the folder then it is moved to my gmail account, visible from gmail.com

I would like to have a unique folder where I put everything related to Work but that dispatch the mails following the accounts they are from.

A mail received about work in Gmail and another one in Yahoo would appear in the same folder in Thunderbird but would appear in their respective work folder in Yahoo.com and Gmail.com.

More than how... is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Thunderbird can search for work-related mails, for example because you tagged them as "work" or they are sent from some address @your-company.com, you can save that search as a virtual folder. This virtual folder will be assigned to one of your mail accounts and displayed in its list of folders, but you can configure it to search in any folder of any account.

Do a search for your work-related mails, for example "Tags include 'work'" or "From includes 'my-company.com'". At the bottom of that dialog, there should be a button to store that search as a virtual folder.

Pressing that button should give you another dialog. There you can set the virtual folders name, at which account it should be displayed, which folders it should search in and the search criteria.

With that, you can for example create a virtual folder called "work for my-company.com" under your Gmail account, that searches in Gmail/work, Yahoo/work and Yahoo/other-stuff for mails that have been sent from an @my-company.com address or are tagged "work".